# rotate the device see the detail view objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, vertical-alignment

I have a UITableView, with rows, when you click on each row you will see the detail view,
I 'm looking for any tutorial or hints for -> if I rotate the device and select my row from the list, I have to  view the description.(I mean in the left I have to have my rows and in right my detail view) Rotating the device back to vertical and hide the detail view.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nice idea but you are increasing workload. You will need to have two views in one view controller or in one .xib file. 2nd, for which row you will display the details in details view?

Comment: why you are not using UISplitViewController? it suites your demand.

Comment: @Popeye yes I plan to use that but I have problem for using in iPhone, Would you please help me if you have any hints or good tutorial?

Comment: I think its for iPad..So, i told. its not possible in iphone to use uisplitviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two view controllers when you rotate you device in horizontal direction, you can try for container views if you are using storyboards that would be reusable in both the directions and probably suit your purpose.